# What is the definition of an "unpublished API", as mentioned in the Slack Developer Policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-design, slack-api

According to the [Slack App Developer Policy](https://api.slack.com/developer-policy), under Security, developers are prohibited from, among other things:

> Using unpublished APIs

What does this mean, exactly?

As a web developer, I typically use AWS API Gateway to deploy my APIs.  According to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-publish-your-apis.html):

> Once you've deployed your APIs, you can publish them by deploying a
>   developer portal, and you can sell your APIs as a SaaS through the AWS
>   Marketplace.

I don't particularly have an interest in selling API access through the AWS Marketplace, but it sounds like this is a requirement in order to publish on Slack.

Furthermore, in the [same section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-developer-portal.html) I'm told my customers can easily:

> - Discover which APIs are available.
> - Browse your API documentation.
> - Register for – and immediately receive – their own API key that can be used to build applications.
> - Try out your APIs in the developer portal UI.
> - Monitor their own API usage.

Is all of this required to integrate with my Slack app?

My workflow typically involves setting up a [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) app as the front-end, and connecting to a custom-built API in the back-end, using code like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
```

where "https://api.example.com" would be an api I've created.  Is this the wrong approach?  Or else am I obligated to go through the steps above to make this api publicly available, as outlined above?

My understanding is that this is a security issue, and the goal is that sensitive data doesn't get stored in some insecure place.  I don't understand how publishing an api corrects this problem.  Furthermore, I believe there's a difference between "public" and "private", and "published" and "unpublished", although I don't understand the details.

Help would be appreciated!  I don't want to inadvertently break the terms of the policy through a lack of research.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in this case they are talking about the unpublished and private api functions that are included in iOS/Cocoa by apple.  Apple's api's have a bunch of hidden and undocumented functionality. Some of this functionality harms security and isn't something the average app should really do. In this case, I doubt that they are talking about whatever service you have deployed on AWS.

Comment: Interesting question. I think this might refer to the unpublished APIs from Slack. But I would strongly recommend to ask the Slack team to clarify it. Here is an overview of known undocumented APIs from Slack: https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc